# How can I get rid of division operator?

Tags: c, optimization, micro-optimization

Instead of writing " / 6 ", what should I write so that I can get rid of division operator ?

```
int a ;
c =  a / 6 ;
```

If you know more on that topic, can you give me general algorithm when b != multiple of 2 ?

ex :

b = 1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 9, 10 , etc

Comment: Hint: *Division is just repeated subtraction.*

Comment: Another hint: you can multiply by the result of 1/6.

Comment: I will have to ask you to give some clarifications on the question: 
 - do you want to get the whole part of division? 
 - is the division only by 2^k 
 - what is b? 
 - do you mean multiple of 2 or power of 2?

Comment: @DOK - How do you calculate `1/6`?

Comment: @opalgo aren't `6` and `10` multiples of 2?

Comment: @DOK: Without resorting to fixed or floating point casts, `1 / 6 == 0` so all results would be `0`.

Comment: @opalgo - If this isn't homework then what is the point of the question? Why are you trying to do this?

Comment: On older CPUs, multiplication was quite a costly operation so was often represented by a series of additions and shift operations. The same is possible with division (with one large caveat). Example: 640 (height of older displays, a multiplication by this is required to index a pixel on screen) = 512 + 128. So number * 640 = number << 9 + number << 7.

Comment: Also, I note that the author has tagged the question as "optimization", so it's worth pointing out that in modern processor architectures this is rarely an optimization.

Comment: If the question means "b != power of 2", there is an exact answer in chapter 16.9 " Division (all processors)" of [this pdf](http://www.agner.org/optimize/optimizing_assembly.pdf).

Comment: @Tim Gee: It doesn't work the same for division, since the decision to subtract or not at a certain stage depends on the partial result from the previous stage, whereas in multiplication this decision is simply from the bits in the multiplier. So you can do a single-cycle multiplier but not a single-cycle divider. The best you can do with division is pipeline it a lot so it can perform similar to single-cycle if you do a lot of them at once.

Comment: The fastest way of performing 32-bit or 64-bit integer division is to use the instruction provided by the CPU. As an alternative, you could change "int a" to "double a" and multiple it by "double(1/6)" - but you would need to careful about the potential consequences of the loss of integer precision in your program.

Comment: @Atom Really not true. If you're dividing by a compile time constant there are possible optimizations, where we replace one division with a multiplication and some adds and shifts. Which is still faster than a division on modern CPUs. But fun thing: Compiler writers know those tricks too (it turns out they do think about these things - who'd have thought) - and yes modern compilers do these things? So really a prime example for a non-optimizations.

Comment: http://www.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html

Answer (score 1):

Well, shift-and-subtract (the general form of replacing `/` with `>>` and optionally `-`, commonly seen for power-of-2 divisors) is what the division operation does for an `int`, so I'm not sure how you'd be expected to eliminate it. If they say to replace it with modulus (`%`), I'd find them hard to take seriously. For `float` or `double`, you could try multiplication by the reciprocal (which moves the division into compile-time instead of run-time), so long as you don't lose too much precision, but that's trickier for integral types without resorting to fixed point representation.